# Linked models showing hidden objects used for modifiers

Tags: modifiers, linked-data, boolean-modifier

I've created a few scenes to be used as linked objects in another scene, and a few of them are using boolean modifiers to "cut" out shapes from other objects. I've noticed that when linking the objects to the main scene, the shapes used for the boolean modifier are still visible.

*Main Scene*
[image]

*Source Scene*
[image]

I've disabled the objects from view and render:
[image]

but I'm assuming I'm missing something else, and I can't seem to find any info about it anywhere. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to recommend to disable in **Viewports Globally** (check Filter options) ...

[image]

... but even with this enabled I just linked it at it is hidden as welll, hmm.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to have worked